# Connect to database in docker container on remote host with pgadmin3

Tags: postgresql, ssh, docker, pgadmin

I'm trying to connect to a database running in a docker container on a remote host. I configured SSH-Tunnel in pgadmin3 with ip of the host and identity file. On Settings tab I inserted `172.18.0.2` (the container IP) as host. It is not possible to connect. pgadmin turns grey for a while and presents me a beautiful error message:

> SSH error: Error when starting up SSH session with error code -8 [Unable to exchange encryption keys]

Do I miss something? Is it possible to connect to the container?

[image]

Comment: What's your ssh tunnel configuration ?

Comment: As described I use the ssh tab in pgadmin server configuration. I'm using the IP of the remote host and a key file. If I using this in pycharm everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

When I upgraded pgAdmin 1.20.0 to 1.22.1, I started getting the same error. pgAdmin 4 doesn't have support for any SSH tunnel either. So, the only option you have right now is .. revert back to 1.20.0. Unfortunately, if you're on PG9.5 or better, pgAdmin 1.20.0 doesn't support it.

Comment: After hours and hours and banging my head, I could make it work thanks to your suggestion. pgAdmin 1.22.1 has issues with ssh tunnel. I could make it work by using pgAdmin 1.20.0 and PG 9.4.

Answer (score 3):

If you require access to a Postgres 9.5 database, you can manually create the SSH tunnel, and then connect using pgAdmin3 by setting the host to `localhost`. On Linux or Mac, you can use the following: `ssh -L 5432:<pg-host>:5432 <jump-host-ip-or-dns>`. It doesn't seem likely that pgAdmin3 will receive any updates with the direction pgAdmin4 is heading.

Comment: How does this work with the docker container IP on the remote host?  Is that docker IP what you mean by `pg-host` here?

Comment: @Kev if you replace `<pg-host>` with the docker ip and the jump-host with the remote host, that should work fine